# Regex for the dot character?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to detect a 'bullet' character followed by some text. For example:

`• This is some text here`

Can someone tell me what is the regex to detect the 'bullet' character `•` in python? What is this symbol?

Comment: See my answer to the same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39394437/python-regex-replacing-u2022/43214837#43214837

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just `•`, but you may have to do a little dance to get it in your source file.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
pattern = re.compile(ur'•')
```

Comment: +1 Thank you. I accepted this beacause it seems like it but somehow it does not work for me even when I set the encoding and specified the `ur` bit. I am using this to define a TOKEN for a parser I am writing using PLY. Do you have any idea why it might not be working?

Comment: Sorry I take that back. It might be an issue on my side in that I might be doing something wrong with the grammar. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -2):

Well, a dot is a special character in a regex pattern. So if you want to sepcify a dot you need to escape the special charactr dot like that:

```
import re

regx = re.compile('\.ab..')

ss = ',ab123  .ab4578  !ab1298   .abUVMO'

print regx.findall(ss)

# result:  ['.ab45', '.abUV']
```

Comment: The question isn't about matching period `'.'`, but about matching the bullet character `•`.

Comment: Sorry! I should've clarified that I was asking about the bullet character. I updated my question.

Comment: @pcurry Thank you. I didn't read the question carefully enough. But note that the title induces in error: _"Regex for the dot character?"_