# Python regex replacing \u2022

Tags: python, regex

This is my string:

```
raw_list = u'Software Engineer with a huge passion for new and innovative products. Experienced gained from working in both big and fast-growing start-ups.  Specialties \u2022 Languages and Frameworks: JavaScript (Nodejs, React), Android, Ruby on Rails 4, iOS (Swift) \u2022 Databases: Mongodb, Postgresql, MySQL, Redis \u2022 Testing Frameworks: Mocha, Rspec xxxx Others: Sphinx, MemCached, Chef.'
```

I'm trying to replace the `\u2022` with just a space.

```
x=re.sub(r'\u2022', ' ', raw_list)
```

But it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need to use the `re` module to do this. Just use the `.replace()` method of your unicode strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using a raw string, with the `r`. That tells Python to interpret the string literally, instead of actually taking escaped characters (such as \n).

```
>>> r'\u2022'
'\\u2022'
```

You can see it's actually a double backslash. Instead you want to use >>> `u'\u2022'` and then it will work.

Note that since you're doing a simple replacement you can just use the `str.replace` method:

```
x = raw_list.replace(u'\u2022', ' ')
```

You only need a regex replace for complicated pattern matching.

Comment: Note that the `re` module does interpret **most** string escape sequences Python supports. `\uhhhh` just happens to be one that *isn't* supported. You can still use a raw string literal, just adding `u` in front makes it interpret Unicode escape sequences.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you use a *Unicode* string literal, the `\uhhhh` escape sequence has no meaning. Not to Python, and not to the `re` module. Add the `u` prefix:

```
re.sub(ur'\u2022', ' ', raw_list)
```

Note the `ur` there; that's a raw unicode string literal; this still interprets `\uhhhh` unicode escape sequences (but is otherwise identical to the standard raw string literal mode). The `re` module doesn't support such escape sequences itself (but it does support most other Python string escape sequences).

Not that you need to use a regular expression here, a simple [`unicode.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) would suffice:

```
raw_list.replace(u'\u2022', u' ')
```

or you can use [`unicode.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
raw_list.translate({0x2022: u' '})
```

Comment: "this still interprets `\uhhhh` unicode escape sequences" - wow, I was not expecting that to be the case. I don't know why they would have made it work that way. It looks like they [completely removed `ur` in Python 3.3](http://bugs.python.org/issue15096) to avoid the issue of whether `ur` should be really-raw or only-somewhat-raw like Python 2.

Comment: @user2357112: You don't need `ur'...'` in Python 3 because a) `r'...'` is already a unicode string (since strings are always unicode strings in Python 3) and b) the `re` module does support `\uhhhh` sequences in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach, changing regex pattern, you might try

```
re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+','',raw_list)
```

> Out[1]: u'Software Engineer with a huge passion for new and
>   innovative products. Experienced gained from working in both big and
>   fast-growing start-ups.  Specialties  Languages and Frameworks:
>   JavaScript (Nodejs, React), Android, Ruby on Rails 4, iOS (Swift) 
>   Databases: Mongodb, Postgresql, MySQL, Redis  Testing Frameworks:
>   Mocha, Rspec xxxx Others: Sphinx, MemCached, Chef.'

Answer (score 0):

The key is to add the unicode `u` in front of the unicode character that you're trying to find - in this case the `\u2022` which is the unicode character for a bullet.  If your text contains unicode characters then your text is actually unicode text as opposed to a string (you can confirm by printing out your text and looking for the u at the beginning).  See the below example, where I search for a unicode bullet character using regular expressions (RegEx) on both a string and unicode text:

***import regular expressions package:***

```
import re
```

***unicode text:***

```
my_unicode = u"""\u2022 Here\'s a string of data.\n<br/>\u2022 There are new 
line characters \n, HTML line break tags <br/>, and bullets \u2002 together in 
a sequence.\n<br/>\u2022 Our goal is to use RegEx to identify the sequences."""

type(my_unicode) #unicode
```

***string:***

```
my_string = """\u2022 Here\'s a string of data. \n<br/>\u2022There are new 
line characters \n, HTML line break tags <br/>, and bullets \u2002 together in 
a sequence.\n<br/>\u2022 Our goal is to use RegEx to identify the sequences."""

type(my_string)     #string
```

***we successfully find the first piece of text that we're looking for which doesn't yet contain the unicode characters:***

```
re.findall('\n<br/>', my_unicode)

re.findall('\n<br/>', my_string)
```

***with the addition of the unicode character, neither substring can be found:***

```
re.findall('\n<br/>\u2022', my_unicode)

re.findall('\n<br/>\u2022', my_string)
```

***Adding four backslashes works for the string, but it does not work for the unicode text:***

```
re.findall('\n<br/>\\\\u', my_unicode)

re.findall('\n<br/>\\\\u', my_string)
```

***Solution: Include the unicode `u` in front of the unicode character:***

```
re.findall('\n<br/>' u'\u2022', my_unicode)
```